# What is the cleanest way to maintain the latest state of a variable which is used in multiple functions?

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose I have a class which includes three helper functions and one main function which calls all the helper functions, as demonstrated below:

```
class SpecificTest(test_runner.BaseSpecificTest):

    def func1 (self):

        varA = []

    def func2 (self):

    def func3 (self):

    def do_all (self):
        self.func1()
        self.func2()
        self.func3()
```

Suppose `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are using the same variable (named `varA`), and the latest variable value should be kept when moving from one function to another.  The `varA` value is inititialized in `func1()`.

Should I use the variable using the `self` keyword, i.e. `self.varA`?

By using `self`, all functions in the class can access it, so it saves me from passing the variable as an argument.

So instead of having `func1(var)`, `func2(var)` and `func3(var)`, I just :

1. use `self.varA` in `func1`, `func2`, and `func3` body.
2. pass only `self` as an argument to `func1`, `func2` and `func3`.
3. call the functions `func1`, `func2` and `func3` using `self`.

Is this the cleanest way? as you can see, I did not use any constructor here in which I initialized the variable `varA`, and Python still accepts it.

Should I define a constructor in which I initialize all the variables used in multiple function in the same class, so they will be referred as the class attributes? in this case, I will just

1. define a constructor in which I initialize all the variables used in multiple function under the class.
2. use `varA` (no need for `self`) in `func1`, `func2`, and `func3` body.
3. No need to pass `self` when calling the `func1`, `func2` and `func3`.

And last question: is it true that you pass `self` as argument only when you call functions in the same class?

Comment: where is the value coming from ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your inputs. the variable value is initialized in func1(). I now edited the question accordingly.

Comment: make it an attribute of the class `self.varA = []` and modify that

Comment: Why do you think you don't need `self` to access class attributes (do you actually *mean* class attributes, or instance attributes)? `funcN` are instance methods, and should always have the `self` argument. And to your last question: as opposed to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialise the var as an attribute and modify that attribute in your methods:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def f1(self):
        self.val += 1
    def f2(self):
        self.val += 1
    def f3(self):
        self.val += 1
    def all(self):
        self.f1()
        self.f2()
        self.f3()
f = Foo()
f.all()
print(f.val)
3
```

I don't see any reason why you would not just add varA as an instance attribute unless you are modifying the attribute in all instances of your class in which case you would use a class attribute:

```
class Foo():
    val = 0

    def f1(self):
        Foo.val += 1
    def f2(self):
        Foo.val += 1
    def f3(self):
        Foo.val += 1
    def all(self):
        self.f1()
        self.f2()
        self.f3()

f = Foo()
f1 = Foo()
f.all()
f1.all()
print(f.val)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SpecificTest(test_runner.BaseSpecificTest):
    def __init__(self):
        self.varA=0
    def func1 (self):

    def func2 (self):

    def func3 (self):
```